# IONIC React input label alignment issue

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, input

I am using Ionic React

but there seems to be issues with the alignment of labels and inputs

they do not center within the input. the alignment is completely off

(I have added border around to show, but there is no other css custom)

I have tried a new project and looking on online examples and this seems to be the case in all of them

The code is just the raw code

```
    <IonItem>
      <IonLabel position="stacked">Username</IonLabel>
      <IonInput></IonInput>
    </IonItem>

    <IonItem lines='none'>
      <IonLabel position="floating">Email</IonLabel>
      <IonInput
        value={email}
        onIonChange={onEmailChange}
      ></IonInput>
    </IonItem>


ion-input {
  background: rgba(250,250,250,1);
  border: solid 1px rgba(218,218,218,1);
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

please help

[image]

Comment: also add your css.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I have added the only CSS i have. this is just to add the border
but like i say, even when i create a new fresh app with ionic start myApp tabs --type react
i have this issue too

Comment: I see what is wrong. Try adding same css on `IonItem` not on ion input.

Comment: the same? my css only is to show the border. it doesnt effect the alignment/placement issue, i just get a border around everything when i do this

Comment: check this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-006-smhwza?file=pages%2FLogin.js,style.css

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib thank you, but this seems to be fine when you have a placeholder. it forces it to stacked.
but if you remove the placeholder from the input and set the label to "floating" position
you will see my issue :(

Comment: For me it looks absolutely fine without placeholder and label as floating. can you recreate stackblitz with your issue.

Comment: actually you say this I think i might understand my issue
when you put the border around the item, it looks fine in floating
but it is only when you put it round the input it looks strange and out of place

Comment: Yes. as label is outside of input it will cause the issue. thats why i asked you to add css on ion item. it will wrap both inside.